# munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer, when to use free()

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free

I'm curious as to why `free(myWord->w)` would be an invalid pointer? I allocate memory to it, so shouldn't I free it as well? or does freeing a struct also free all of its fields?

New to C so any insight on the world of pointers is much appreciated!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct word {
    char *w;
} WORD;

void setWord(char **f);

int main() {

    WORD *myWord = malloc(sizeof(WORD));
    myWord->w = malloc(6);
    strcpy(myWord->w, "hello"); // set to "hello"
    setWord(&(myWord->w));      // set to "bagel"


    free(myWord->w); /* munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer. Aborted (core dumped) */
    free(myWord);

    return 0;

}

void setWord(char **F) {
    *F = "bagel";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`*F = "bagel";` is not how you assign a string. Instead the code overwrite the value of the pointer `myWord->w` so when you call `free`, it's no longer the correct pointer value.

To see that the pointer change, try this:

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)myWord->w);
setWord(&(myWord->w));      // set to "bagel"
printf("%p\n", (void*)myWord->w);
```

Consequently, the `free` call will fail as the pointer-value isn't the one you got from the `malloc`.

So instead of `*F = "bagel";` use

```
strcpy(*F, "bagel");   // NOT: *F = "bagel"
```

Further you don't need to pass the address of `w`. Simply do:

```
void setWord(char *F) {
    strcpy(F, "bagel");
}
```

and call it like:

```
setWord(myWord->w);
```

And...

> I allocate memory to it, so shouldn't I free it as well? or does freeing a struct also free all of its fields?

Yes, you must `free` it.

No, `free` of a struct does **not** `free` members automatically. You must do that.

Comment: Thanks so much, this makes perfect sense!